# Yii2 create user table

Tags: php, database, yii, yii2-advanced-app

I installed Yii 2 with advanced application template to my localhost everything is fine except command migrate when I use cmd to create user table it doesn't do any thing. My code in main-local : 
"I:\zzerver\Uwamp -port 84\uw-cms-p8585\www\yii1\common\config\main-local.php"

is :

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost:8585;dbname=db001name001',
            'username' => 'db001user001',
            'password' => 'yii2db001',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
    ],
];
```

I did change localhost:8585 to 127.0.0.1:8585 but still has the same problem, I'm using phpmyadmin, and server is Uwamp

the init command work good but when I try : php yii migrate or yii migrate 
no thing happen. this is the cmd

[image]

that all what it show , and nothing created in database

I did download "Yii 2 with advanced application template" 
after that I did open cmd and run php init

```
I:\zzerver\Uwamp -port 84\uw-cms-p8585\www\yii1>php init
Yii Application Initialization Tool v1.0

Which environment do you want the application to be initialized in?

  [0] Development
  [1] Production

  Your choice [0-1, or "q" to quit] 0

  Initialize the application under 'Development' environment? [yes|no] y

  Start initialization ...

      exist backend/config/main-local.php
            ...overwrite? [Yes|No|All|Quit] All
  overwrite backend/config/main-local.php
  unchanged backend/config/params-local.php
  unchanged backend/config/test-local.php
  unchanged backend/web/index-test.php
  unchanged backend/web/index.php
  unchanged backend/web/robots.txt
  overwrite common/config/main-local.php
  unchanged common/config/params-local.php
  unchanged common/config/test-local.php
  unchanged console/config/main-local.php
  unchanged console/config/params-local.php
  overwrite frontend/config/main-local.php
  unchanged frontend/config/params-local.php
  unchanged frontend/config/test-local.php
  unchanged frontend/web/index-test.php
  unchanged frontend/web/index.php
  unchanged frontend/web/robots.txt
  unchanged yii
  unchanged yii_test
  unchanged yii_test.bat
   generate cookie validation key in backend/config/main-local.php
   generate cookie validation key in frontend/config/main-local.php
      chmod 0777 backend/runtime
      chmod 0777 backend/web/assets
      chmod 0777 frontend/runtime
      chmod 0777 frontend/web/assets
      chmod 0755 yii
      chmod 0755 yii_test

  ... initialization completed.


I:\zzerver\Uwamp -port 84\uw-cms-p8585\www\yii1>
```

I created database name : db001name001, user : db001name001, password : yii2db001,

I add information to common\config\main-local.php

I did open again cmd and run php yii migrate

```
I:\zzerver\Uwamp -port 84\uw-cms-p8585\www\yii1>php yii migrate
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.13-dev)
```

but nothing happen no table created for user, I want to create table for user to start creating a signup form

common\config\main-local.php

```
<?php
return [
        'components' => [
            'db' => [
                'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
                'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost:8585;dbname=db001name001',
                'username' => 'db001user001',
                'password' => 'yii2db001',
                'charset' => 'utf8',
            ],
            'mailer' => [
                'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
                'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
                // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
                // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
                // for the mailer to send real emails.
                'useFileTransport' => true,
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

common\config\main.php:

```
    <?php
    return [
        'aliases' => [
            '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
            '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
        ],
        'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
        'components' => [
            'cache' => [
                'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

my console console\config\main.php"

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params.php',
    require __DIR__ . '/params-local.php'
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-console',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers',
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
    'controllerMap' => [
        'fixture' => [
            'class' => 'yii\console\controllers\FixtureController',
            'namespace' => 'common\fixtures',
          ],
    ],
    'components' => [
        'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

Comment: show your console/config/main.php  (or main-local)

Comment: return [
    'aliases' => [
        '@bower' => '@vendor/bower-asset',
        '@npm'   => '@vendor/npm-asset',
    ],
    'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
    ],
];

Comment: please update your question and add the code

Comment: don't post code in comment  .. please update your question .. with code properly formatted ..

Comment: i have asked for console .. code non for common code  ..

Answer (score 0):

Going by only the information you provided, I'd suggest that you read about Yii2 migrations [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-migrations.html). In your example you did not provide any commands to Yii, just checked if the migration tool is installed. After/If you've done that, please, clarify your question - show us what commands you've tried to run, and the error messages too, if there's any.

The linked documentation has a few examples, including code for creating tables, the same thing you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

at the first look ssems you have not db component seeting in your console/config/main.php

try add a proper db connect eg for mysql

```
<?php
    $params = array_merge(
        require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
        require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
        require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
        require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
    );


    return [
        'id' => 'app-console',
        'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
        'bootstrap' => ['log'],
        'controllerNamespace' => 'console\controllers',
        'components' => [
            'log' => [
                'targets' => [
                    [
                        'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                        'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'db' => [

                'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
                'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db_name',
                'username' => 'my_root',
                'password' => 'my_pwd',
                'charset' => 'utf8',
                'enableSchemaCache' => true, 

            ],

      ],
      'params' => $params,
  ];
```

and then  try run you migration command

Comment: you code give me this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting ']' in I:\zzerver\Uwamp -port 84\uw-cms-p8585\www\yii1\common\config\main.php on line 32

Comment: my code is not the complete code for you config file but is just a suggestion for remeber you that yuou need  a valid connection to db .. anyway amswer  update with formed  array ..